# Controlador en ANgularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute

En esta ocasión escribo por que tengo un problema en una pequeña app de AngularJS y es que estoy intentando conectarme a un controlador con un ejemplo que leo en un libro, pero no me esta mostrando la variable $scope que declaré en el controlador.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

routing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Rutas</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controladores/controladorseccion1.js"></script>
        <style>
            ul{margin: 0; padding: 0; margin: auto; width: 400px;}
            li{float: left; height: 30px; list-style-type: none; width: 100px;}
            a{display: block}
            h2{color: red}
            div{clear: both}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="routingApp">
        <div id="menu" data-ng-include="'plantillas/menu.html'"></div>
        <div id="contenedor" data-ng-view></div>
        <script>
            var miRouting = angular.module('routingApp', ['ngRoute']);
            miRouting.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/seccion1', {
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/seccion1.html',
                    controller: 'miControlador'
                }).when('/seccion2', {
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/seccion2.html',
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/inicio.html',
                });
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

tienda.html:

```
<h1>Tienda de pantalones</h1>
```

menu.html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#!/">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/seccion1">Sección 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/seccion2">Sección 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

seccion1.html:

```
<h1>Sección 1</h1>
<p>Estas viendo la primera sección</p>
<h2> {{ mensaje }} </h2>
```

sección2.html:

```
<h1>Sección 2</h1>
<p>Estas viendo la segunda sección</p>
```

controladorseccion1.js:

```
miRouting.controller('miControlador', function($scope){
    $scope.mensaje = 'Esta es una variable almacenada en el controlador';
})
```

La estructura es la siguiente:
routing.html
controladores/controladorseccion1.js
plantillas/inicio.html
plantillas/menu.html
plantillas/seccion1.html
plantillas/seccion2.html

El problema en este caso es que la variable $scope.mensaje no esta mostrando el valor que le asigne y aparece "{{ mensaje }}" de la siguiente manera:

Sección 1
Estas viendo la primera sección

{{ mensaje }}

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: agrega el data-ng-controller="miControlador" al body y me dices si te funciona, veo que no lo estas referenciando

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, sin embargo ya habia intentado con eso y me aparece todo en blanco, el controlador si lo estoy referenciando en el $routeProvider: `$routeProvider.when('/seccion1', {
     templateUrl: 'plantillas/seccion1.html',
     controller: 'miControlador'
    })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya encontré tu error y es que estas cargando primero el controlador y luego el script que tienes el body, es por eso que no reconoce la variable miRouting.controller(... lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente: 1) Cargar el controlador después del `script` del `body`. 2) trasladar ese código del `body` a tu controlador.

```
<body data-ng-app="routingApp">
        <div id="menu" data-ng-include="'plantillas/menu.html'"></div>
        <div id="contenedor" data-ng-view></div>
        <script>
            var miRouting = angular.module('routingApp', ['ngRoute']);
            miRouting.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/seccion1', {
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/seccion1.html',
                    controller: 'miControlador'
                }).when('/seccion2', {
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/seccion2.html',
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'plantillas/inicio.html',
                });
            }]);
        </script>
        <script src="controladores/controladorseccion1.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Esto funcionara perfectamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, efectivamente ese era el problema,